# cloud9でphpMyAdminのindex.phpに接続できない

Tags: python, django, phpmyadmin

【実現したいこと】
cloud9でphpMyadminのindex.phpページに接続したいです．

【前提】
Django/python3を使っています．

【問題】
https://*****.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php
に接続したのですが，以下の画像の通りのエラーとなり，Page not foundとなってしまいます．
ちなみに，https://*****.amazonaws.com/には問題なく接続できております．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

フォルダ構成は以下の通りです．
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

urls.pyファイルは以下の通りです．

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include('memo.urls')),
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

【試したこと】
urls.pyのファイルにphpMyAdmin用にルートを設定しないといけないのかと考え，以下のようにしてみましたがダメでした．

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include('memo.urls')),
    path(r'', include('phpMyAdmin.urls')),
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

お手数をおかけしますが，お力をお借りできると助かります．

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/173259

Comment: phpmyadmin と Django/python3は別のドキュメントルートにするなど分けることはできないですか？言語も違うサーバサイドのフレームワークとツールを同居となるとなかなか骨が折れる作業だなという印象があります